# How can I generically .Include properties of entities limited to a certain class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, func

I am using Entity Framework 6.x with T4 templates to generate both my `DbContext` and my entity classes from my `.edmx`. All of my entities inherit a class called `BaseEntity`. Take for example the following sample entity:

```
public partial class UserEntity : BaseEntity {
    [IdentityColumn]
    public int Id  { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int fkUserLocationId { get; set; }

    [NavigationColumn]
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }   
    [NavigationColumn]
    public virtual UserLocation UserLocation { get; set; }
}
```

`UserRole` and `UserLocation` also inherit `BaseEntity`. I have a generic repository interface `IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity` and an implementation of that `GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity: BaseEntity`:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity {
    protected readonly MyDbContext _context;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(MyDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    //Would like to limit object to be of type BaseEntity or ICollection<BaseEntity>
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        var query = _dbSet.AsQueryable();
        foreach (var include in includeProperties){
            query = query.Include(include);
        }

        return query;
    }
}
```

With all of that, I am able to easily include entities by doing something like:

```
//Assume this repository already exists
_userRepository.Get(user => user.UserRoles, user => user.UserLocation); //Valid include
_userRepository.Get(user => user.Name); //Invalid include but appears in Intellisense
```

How can I correctly define this method that that only `BaseEntity` properties (or properties with the `NavigationColumn` attribute) are valid in that `Func`?

Comment: Thank you for that entirely useless and generic comment, this is a dumbed down class because I didn't feel like putting all of the code here.

Comment: Is there a reason for needing this over just a generic include for anything implementing `BaseEntity`?

Comment: I would be curious to see any use for the generic repository

Comment: @Shoe Yes because I need to be able to Include ICollection<BaseEntity> as well.

Comment: Whether or not a generic repository is useful is not my question so your opinion in this case is not relevant.

Comment: Wouldn't a generic Include cover that though? What you seem to want is to be able to be more restrictive about what you can include. I'm just asking why there's a need to be restrictive at all, given includes are perfectly valid for other objects.

Comment: Is an Include valid for a non-navigation property (such as the `Name` property defined above)? It doesn't make sense to me to .Include that as it's just a column in my entity.

Comment: can't you add a where restriction on the end of your Get method?

Comment: Not sure, that is what I am asking. What where condition will restrict to `BaseEntity` and `ICollection<BaseEntity>`?

Comment: No it isn't valid for non-navs but it will be valid for more than things implementing `BaseEntity`. Is that a valid compromise?

Comment: @Shoe When you say a generic include, you mean the one I have already in the code, correct?

Comment: Yes, your `Get` is really an `Include` method.

Comment: I think perhaps this is unclear...I am happy with the structure of my repository and the use of my `Get` method, I was just looking for a better way to filter properties that are valid to include (navigation properties) versus properties of my entities (columns in my table).

Comment: Currently there is no way to do that. As you saw, `object` allows you to attempt to include `strings` and such. And even if you specified a generic parameter there's no way to constrain that parameter to what you want. The best you can get is the ability to do multiple includes with exceptions that get thrown when you try to include something invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity {
    protected readonly MyDbContext _context;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(MyDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    //Would like to limit object to be of type BaseEntity or ICollection<BaseEntity>
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        var query = _dbSet.AsQueryable();
//Something like that may help? wont solve the issue of intelisense knowing what is allowed and what is not allowed. 

        includeProperties = includeProperties.Where(p=>p.Type.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NavigationProperty),true).Any());

        foreach (var include in includeProperties){
            query = query.Include(include);
        }

        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work because while it doesn't 100% solve my intellisense issue it will at least not throw an exception if someone uses it wrong.

Comment: A silent fail when someone passes the wrong property into the method? That sounds frustrating to me at least.

Comment: It would be fairly easy for me to add some log4net logging in this method (a WARN level perhaps).

Comment: I also feel like the spirit of the issue is not the individual properties, those will be included with the navigation property. You could add logic to include the parent navigation property if someone attempts to add a property.

x=>X.UserLocation.PositionX ... (if they included a property of UserLocation and UserLocation is a Navigation Property of X than include UserLocation) Now that sounds like some recursive nightmare crap in order to escape what is essentially a rare problem. KISS?